# Exchange 2010 "Cannot send on behalf of user"

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2010, email-bounces

I am getting a bounceback when sending an email from another account, the error is "You can't send a message on behalf of this user unless you have permission to do so. Please make sure you're sending on behalf of the correct sender, or request the necessary permission. If the problem continues, please contact your helpdesk.

The problem is I am not trying to send on behalf of any of the bounceback addresses, I am trying to send TO them. I have enabled "Send-As" and "Full Access" permissions to the account.

The message will successfully send to all recipients if I put all the addresses in the "CC:" field with no adresses in the "TO:" field, as soon as I put an address in the "TO:" field it will bounceback from ALL the addresses including the ones in the "CC:" field.

I have tried this on the users machine and my own machine with the same result.

Any ideas??

Comment: This might be old and irrelevant, but it's certainly an interesting issue

Why do you need to enable "Send-As" and "Full Access" if you are sending it to this user from your own account? From how I read this, it seems like you are entering the problematic user's account in the TO field when you encounter this issue?

If this is an issue specifically to a user, you might want to cleanrule for this problematic user. However, I am not sure if I understood the issue fully